# with bxSlider and Mocha for testing how do i avoid using setTimeout to wait for slide transitions?

Tags: integration-testing, mocha.js, bxslider

i'm using BxSlider and writing integration tests with mocha, along with testem.

if you start at slide 0, and then call twice in a row: slider.goToNextSlide(); slider.goToNextSlide(); , it only advances to slide 1, not slide 2.

this happens because bxslider waits until the transition to the next slide is complete before allowing another goToNextSlide() call.

i'm writing automated tests and i really don't want to use a setTimeout() in the tests to wait for that transition to complete.  setting BxSlider.speed = 0 doesn't work, it breaks the slider.  .speed = 1 still requires waiting for the transition to complete before calling the next goToNextSlide()

how can i avoid using setTimeout() in this case for my automated tests?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stub API to stub setTimeout.

For example, sinon.js allows you to fake time, by stubbing all the time dependent functions.

http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock

Just use

```
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
```

and then, when you want to go forward in time :

```
clock.tick(timeInMilliSeconds);
```

I hope this will help.